# Unable To Change Process Priority On Windows 11 22H2

Tags: windows, windows-11, task-manager, windows-11-v22h2

This happened to me recently after updating to the latest update for Windows 11. When I go to Task Manager and try to change the process priority, I am getting an access denied.

I tried restarting computer as well as running Task Manager as Administrator but it doesn't help.

Another note is that I have a laptop with the exact same Windows version and build, it doesn't have an issue there.

Note:

- I am on Windows 11 Enterprise 22H2 Build 22621.1413
- The process is launched by my local user (not Administrator)
- The devices are private devices, and not own and managed by an IT department.
- Tried with another application, it seem to be application specific (I can change the priority of say Photoshop, but not some particular games)
- The UAC (User Access Control) for is the same on both machine and install as well

[image: Task Manager Access Denied]

[image: Application UAC]

**Update**

Making a quick update. The application just go an update, and the main executable also go updated. I did not make any changes to the permission, but now I can change the Process Priority.

So this was another thing I suspected before, the permission issue might be something that broke after the previous update, and is fix on the current update.

Comment: Which process is it and who launched it?

Comment: @harrymc, i've updated the description, but the process is launched by my own users, and not a system process and not Administrator, it is a game.

Comment: @Peregrino69, updated!

Comment: So you're in effect trying to change the priority of a process that you have previously launched? What does this process do, and is it for example waiting on an internet connection?

Comment: @harrymc, so it used to be in Windows 10 that once you set the Priority in Task Manager, it is permanent, but Windows 11 they changed it so it is not, basically say if I start an application like Photoshop or a Game, i want to give it a higher priority

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot of the UAC for the process you are trying to change the priority of as an edit to your question?

Comment: @Ramhound, attached to original post

Comment: So try explicitly giving your user Full Control over the process and see if you can then, without elevating the permissions of task manager, change the priority.\

Comment: i believe this will probably work, and probably also work if i reinstall the application, but this doesn't tell the root cause of the issue, which i would also like to find out, because my other machine with the same build / same version doesn't have this issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing the priority in Task Manager may not stick for several reasons,
mostly if the executable restarts itself. It then loses all attributes
and starts again with the default ones.

To permanently set the priority of a process, do this :

- Find the name of the executable, say `PROGRAM.EXE`
- Create a Text Document with `.reg` extension and enter the following:

  ```
  Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

  [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Image File Execution Options\PROGRAM.EXE]
  [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Image File Execution Options\PROGRAM.EXE\PerfOptions] 
  "CpuPriorityClass"=dword:PRIORITY
  ```
- Replace `PROGRAM.EXE` with your application and change the `PRIORITY`
  to one of the following values:

  ```
  Idle: 1
  Normal: 2 
  High: 3 
  4 : Realtime
  Below Normal: 5 
  Above Normal: 6
  ```
- Double-click to execute the `.reg` file and click Yes and then OK

To undo this change, delete the registry key that you added.

In addition to the `CpuPriorityClass` value, also exists
`IoPriority` with the same numerical values as above,
except that `0` stands for Very Low and the values `5` and `6`
don't exist.

Comment: yes, i do know about the registry setting, and is probably what i will have to go with for now, but one thing it doesn't explain is the root cause of the issue

Answer (score 1):

Check if your user account\group has SeIncreaseBasePriorityPrivilege privilege.
You can check it in Local Group Policy Editor > Computer Configuration > Windows Settings > Security Settings > Local Policies > User Rights Assignment > Increase scheduling priority.

Administrators group has this privilege by default.

Alternatively, you can check it using Sysinternals Accesschk tool using following command-line:
accesschk.exe /accepteula -a SeIncreaseBasePriorityPrivilege

Here's privilege description from policy editor:
This security setting determines which accounts can use a process with Write Property access to another process to increase the execution priority assigned to the other process. A user with this privilege can change the scheduling priority of a process through the Task Manager user interface.

Comment: i check the policy for scheduling on both machines, they are configured the same way. i also check the user and group and computer management, they are also the same